# Is it possible to change a Dual SATA RAID enclosure to a NON-RAID enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

just wanna know if it possible to change a Dual SATA RAID enclosure with a normal USB2.0/3.0 enclosure, like change it to single HDD drive. will it have any problem like cannot detect on PC? Cos I have a friend just pulled out the 2 HDD from the raid enclosure and put it to single 3.5" enclosure but when connect to the PC, the drive not shown in the "My computer" but somehow from the Disk Management we still can the HDD is there. is there anyway that we can retrieve the files inside before doing formatting? Thanks in advance for any advice.